# Display Uniswap USDC/WETH Liquidity Position value in USD

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, blockchain, decentralized-applications, uniswap

[image]

[image]

I have a open position with ID - 508797 & liquidity - 18203455433937 (after being converted from hex toNumber()), I double checked it on etherscan in USDC/WETH pool. What I want to understand is how do i display my share in USD $2.23 like the one i shared in UI. It has to do something with TVL & current price of assets right? I'm missing the calculation to show the value in USD so I would highly appreciate if anyone could guide me or share links / resources.

P.S - using UniswapV3